# Serialising values with problematic characters(% \n... )

Tags: php, database

I have a PHP cart that was pre developed by a company, while ordering, I added an extra field for extra information, the $_POST value of it simply gets added onto the variable $post['attr'], however when that gets serialised and put into a DB it errors if it contains things like %, !, $, etc. well it doesnt error, it sends out pending order email, takes them to paypal, lets them pay, and never verifies that the prder is actually in the DB, which its not if it had special chars in it...

I have tried different ways and read that base64 encoding can help, however that would mean scraping a lot of pre existing orders and re doing a lot of the system, anyone could help?

Thank you!

Comment: If the database query is erroring when special characters are put into the data being inserted, then you're almost CERTAINLY vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should take the cart software out back and burn it at the stake, then spray the developer's offices with poison and napalm.

Comment: If special characters lead to problems, this means that you are not properly escaping.

Comment: *"read that base64 encoding can help"* … looks like you're not using parameterized queries. Without seeing the relevant code this question cannot be answered. Please add the code sections that matter.

Comment: Anyhow I need to somehow replace these chars, this shopping cart system is WP based, anyone know if WP has a function? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using base64 encoding use urlencode function of php while saving into database and then use urldecode to get the actual data

Comment: @rahul - URL encoding is not the same as escaping strings for the database.

Comment: @Brendan Long - You are right, i didnt notice that he need to escape

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that the data isn't be escaped. I'm guessing you're doing something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('". $something ."')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

What you need to do is escape the variable first:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (something) VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($something) ."')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

My example uses MySQL, but similar functions exist for all supported databases.

**Use the correct function for your database. Do not just use url encoding, or generic string escaping. The characters that need to be quoted are database-specific.**